# Is ‘happy darkness’ semantically correct?

Tags: semantics

Is ‘happy darkness’ semantically correct? It means a dark thing is happy, so darkness is happy.

dark shape, dark feeling, dark taste, etc.

I asked this question because I cannot understand ‘hot summer’. How period, that is length, is hot?

Comment: Hot summer = a summer when there are many hot days (in a climate where summer weather is not always hot). _Happy darkness_ is a valid expression if you have a reason for saying that someone finds darkness happy.

Comment: @Kate Bunting ‘Days’ means length of time, measurement... ‘hot measurement’ makes sense?

Comment: _A day_ is a measurement of time, but _day_ does not mean _measurement_! A hot day is one when the weather is hot during daylight hours.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out the source of the confusion. How do you describe a summer during which it is hot in your language?

Comment: @TypelA I have no idea of my language... But if I have a reason, ‘hot smell’ is valid also?

Comment: @Kate Bunting ‘hot smell’ ‘black taste’ could be valid if there’s a reason?

Comment: _Hot smell_ could refer to the smell given off by some substances when they are heated. I can't imagine what a _black taste_ could be. Flavours don't have colours.

Comment: Valid? You mean grammatical? Sure, but the meaning isn't immediately understandable like "hot summer." This is an idiomatic way we describe the climate, specifically the temperature, over a span of time like a summer or a day.

Comment: @Kate Bunting When it comes to imagination, it could be...? I’m sorry for being silly...

Comment: The trouble is the alternatives you're proposing are not idiomatic descriptions. A "hot smell" _might_ mean a _spicy_ smell, but then we would just say that. A "black taste" _might_ mean a charred flavor but then we would just say that. In contrast, "hot summer" is idiomatic and immediately understandable.

Comment: @TypelA I almost understand, but I cannot distinguish quality from manner

Comment: It's _grammatically_ correct to modify a noun with an adjective, but there are many (adjective-noun) combinations that don't make any sense.

Comment: @fararound We like to personify and anthropomorphise things. If a human can be happy, then literally everything could be happy - we are wildly imaginative creatures. Darkness can symbolise many things (death, fear, evil, unknown, depression, sadness, anxiety, loneliness). They don't necessarily make sense if, for you, darkness is nothing but absence of light.

Comment: I'm still confused.  I know several languages, and in all of them "hot summer" is simple to understand.  The only thing I can think of is that some languages use a different word for the temperature of object compared with a description of temperature or the subjective feeling of warmth.  Still I'd like to know more about your language.

Comment: Would you be willing to tell us what your native language is? As JamesK said, this has sparked our curiosity and maybe there is an opportunity for all of us to learn something.

Comment: There is no such thing as "happy darkness" in English as a usual expression. Googling for this will help confirm. Now, could you create this and use it in a short story or something? Sure, as long as you explained it first, because remember, it's not a usual expression in English. Also, you can't create something and then apply it to other things and expect everyone to understand you. No language works like that. Are you a math person?

Comment: @TypelA Korean.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Yes close to a math person

Comment: @James K I’m Korean but I think it covers Chinese and Japanese.

Comment: 日本語では、「暑い夏」と言う。 I'm less confident about Korean but I think 더운여름 makes sense.  At least google agrees with me.   Korean does seem to have the same distiction between hot object and hot feeling.  Japanese has this too, but for "cold". English doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English uses the same word "hot" to refer to objects that have a high temperature

> This is a hot pie.

And weather:

> It was a hot day.

And the subjective feeling

> I am hot and sweaty.

So it is quite normal to describe a summer as "hot". It means the weather during summer.

On the other hand darkness is an abstract quality.  Could such a quality be described as happy?  It seems unlikely.

It is just about possible: A "scary darkness" is possiblem (but not a scared darkness, some languages use the same word for scary and scared. English doesn't). That would be darkness that is likely to cause people to feel scared.  So, a happy darkness could mean a quality darkness that makes people feel happy. But we know that this is not so likely. So "Happy darkness" would be a rare combination of words. It would be limited to poetic meanings.

So the short answer is "happy darkness" is not a meaningful combination of words.

Comment: +1 because you allow for the  poetic "happy darkness of a hot summer night".